# Leitura de caracteres indesejáveis - Python

Tags: python, string, input, caracteres, split

Uma maneira de separar palavras a partir de uma `string` fornecida como no método abaixo:

`entrada = input().split(" ")`

Dúvida: Caso eu queira excluir mais de um caractere específico (" ,&ˆ*!!:") não necessariamente em ordem, não necessariamente agrupado; quais recursos poderia  utilizar?

Exemplo:

```
"João:saiu!! de%$ˆcasa" -------------> "João saiu de casa"
```

Answer (score 8):

Tem uma maneira bem simples utilizando Regex:

```py
import re
input = "João:saiu!! de%$ˆcasa"
pattern = "[,&ˆ*!!:%\$\s]+"
repl = " "

output = re.sub(pattern, repl, input)
print(output)
# João saiu de casa
```

Você pode adicionar novos caracteres para exclusão entre os colchetes na variável `pattern`.

Answer (score 5):

Uma solução:

```py
import re

inp = "João:saiu!! de%$ˆcasa"
pattern = "[a-zà-ú]+"
output = " ".join(re.findall(pattern, inp, re.I))

print(inp)
print(output)
```

ou sem `re.I` (ignorar caso):

```py
import re

inp = "João:saiu!! de%$ˆcasa"
pattern = "[a-zA-ZÀ-ú]+"
output = " ".join(re.findall(pattern, inp))

print(inp)
print(output)
```

Answer (score 5):

Também é possível remover caracteres indesejados sem o uso de expressões regulares.

O classe [str](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str) contém o método [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) que retorna uma cópia da string na qual cada caractere foi mapeado através da tabela de tradução criada com o método estático [`str.maketrans()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) cujo uma de suas implementação aceita dois parâmetros que devem ser strings de igual comprimento, e no dicionário resultante, cada caractere em *x* será mapeado para o caractere na mesma posição em *y*.

```
texto = "João:saiu!! de%$ˆcasa"                              #Texto a ser purgado.
indesejados = ":!%$ˆ"                                        #Caracteres a serem purgados.

tabela = str.maketrans(indesejados, " " * len(indesejados))  #Cria a tabela de tradução onde cada caractere indesejado será mapeado para um caractere de espaço.
novo_texto = " ".join(texto.translate(tabela).split())       #Purga o texto, o descontrói e o reconstrói sem espaços duplicados.

print(novo_texto)                                            #Imprime João saiu de casa
```

Teste o exemplo no [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/n43Lht)